# Springboot Cassandra - com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.SyntaxError: Bind variables cannot be used for keyspace names

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra

Quick question regarding how to have a keyspace name variable within a SpringBoot @Repository please.

I currently have a database that has two different tables in two different keyspaces. But with the exact same data structure.

Sometimes, I need to retrieve from the first keysapce, sometimes the second.
Hence, I wrote the following:

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends ReactiveCassandraRepository<Data, String> {
    
    @Query("select * from ?0.?1 where key = ?2")
    Mono<Data> findByIdCustom(String keyspace, String table, String key);

}
```

However, this yields to

```
org.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraQuerySyntaxException: Query; CQL [com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.DefaultSimpleStatement@eeba944d]; Bind variables cannot be used for keyspace names; nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.SyntaxError: Bind variables cannot be used for keyspace names
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CassandraExceptionTranslator.translate(CassandraExceptionTranslator.java:129) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.1.1.jar!/:3.1.1]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:

Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.SyntaxError: Bind variables cannot be used for keyspace names
```

Is there a way to workaround this without having to hardcode the keyspace in the query please?

Thank you

Comment: Check this out - https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/13647/multiple-keyspaces-with-spring-data-cassandra

Comment: Yes, it is a good blog post. But I would like to resolve this "SyntaxError: Bind variables cannot be used for keyspace names" instead if possible.

Comment: Faced the same issue in quarkus